# Slash in the caption of a Facebook post

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I have a problem while I implement a feature which posts to Facebook. I need to add a `/` character to the caption. Unfortunately, if that is inside the caption string, then on Facebook the part after the slash is not shown. If I define a caption like `foo.bar/username` then `foo.bar` will be shown as the caption. This is not desirable. I tried to escape it with `\/`, in that case, `foo.bar\/username` appeared as the caption. Is there away to show the string containing the slash as caption?

EDIT:
I will give you more details about the problem, since it is seems it is not reproducible in all cases. I have this code, invoking posting to wall:

```
if (fRequest::get("share") === "facebook") {
    $title = "Ask or tell me anything anonymously ";
    $uri = QM::$mainSiteName.User::current()->getUsername();
    $desc = "";
    $msg = "";
    $pic = QM::$mainSiteName . "images/facebook-share-my-link-200x200.png";
    $caption = $uri;
    $action_name = "Ask " . $_SESSION["username"] . " anything";
    $action_link = $uri;        
    App::CurrentUser()->postToFacebookWall($title, $uri, $desc, $msg, $pic, $caption, $action_name, $action_link);
}
```

The code above calls the `postToFacebookWall` function of the user class:

```
public function postToFacebookWall($title, $uri, $desc, $msg = null, $pic = null, $caption = null, $action_name = null, $action_link = null, $uid = 'me') {
    try {
        $data = array(
            'name' => $title,
            'link' => $uri,
            'description' => $desc            
        );

        if ($pic) {
            $data['picture'] = $pic;
        }

        if ($caption) {
            $data['caption'] = $caption;
        }

        if ($action_name) {
            $data['actions'] = json_encode(array('name' => $action_name, 'link' => $action_link));
        }

        Facebook\FacebookAccessor\FacebookAction::facebookActionFactory("post", array("url" => $uri, "params" => $data));
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The code above triggers the action factory:

```
public static function facebookActionFactory($actionKey, $params) {
    $element = new FacebookAction($actionKey, $params);
    switch ($actionKey) {
        case FacebookActionPrivilege::$ACTION_POST_KEY: return $element->post($params["params"]);
        case FacebookActionPrivilege::$ACTION_FIND_FRIENDS_KEY: return $element->findFriends($params["params"]);
        case FacebookActionPrivilege::$ACTION_PICTURE_KEY: return $element->getPicture($params["params"]);
    }
}
```

which, on its turn, triggers the post method:

```
public function post($params) {
    if (($this->getIsPossible()) && (is_array($params))) {
        $postRequest = new FacebookRequest(FacebookActionPrivilege::getSession(), 'POST', '/me/feed', $params);
        $postResponse = $postRequest->execute();
        return $postResponse;
    }
}
```

the last two methods being part of the `FacebookAction` class. The post method triggers the `FacebookRequest` SDK constructor, posting the message.

Note, that QM::$mainSiteName.User::current()->getUsername() generates a string, like `"http://foo.bar/loremipsum"` and in the Facebook post, the caption is: `foo.bar`

Comment: No idea what you problem is. Posting a link to a user timeline with caption `foo.bar/username` works perfectly fine via Graph API Explorer. If it doesn’t work for you, then that might be due to the environment that you are making the post from.

Comment: @CBroe, I do not know where the problem is. I believe it is a bug and the first place I am looking for bugs is in my source-code, however, in this case after several times reading my code I did not find the problematic part. I have tried to work-around it, but without any sensible results. For instance, when I try to escape / with \/, then \/ is shown in the post, but the suffix appear. When I try with only / the / disappear along with the suffix. Strange, but true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having some trial and error sessions it, I found the solution. Instead of

```
$caption = "http://foo.bar/loremipsum";
```

I am using

```
$caption = "foo.bar&nbsp;&frasl;loremipsum";
```

`&frasl;` is to encode the `/` and since the result did not show up well on the facebook wall, I needed some space,solved by `&nbsp;`